# The completion of $C_c^\infty(M)$ with respect to $\lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2(M)}$ on a compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact smooth Riemannian manifold (eg. a smooth hypersurface) and let $X$ be the space given as the completion of $C_c^\infty(M)$ with respect to the norm $\left(\int_{M} |\nabla u|^2\right)^{\frac 12}.$

Is this space well-defined and sensible? What is it used for?  In particular I am interested about the links to using Poincare's equality. This space surely is not the same as $H^1(M)$ since we are neglecting the $L^2$ norm of $u$ in the definition.

If $M$ were an open domain in Euclidean space, I am told that this space corresponds to "choosing Dirichlet conditions". I think in this case $X=H^1_0$ so that kinda makes sense.

Comment: That is not a norm. You may need to restrict to the subspace $\{u:\ \int_M u= 0\}$

Comment: @John: I read: let $M=\Omega$ be an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then define $X$ to be the completion of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ wrt. the norm $\lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^2}$. On an unbounded domain this is not a norm either, right?

Comment: But your $M$ is compact, so it does not make sense to consider $M$ to be an unbounded domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of completion is called *homogeneous Sobolev space* and is denoted $\dot H^1$. In general, dot over the name of a space indicates homogeneous version, meaning the space is equipped with seminorm that takes only one order of derivative into account. The fact that we have a seminorm that not a norm can be a disadvantage sometimes; but on the other hand, the seminorm has nice scaling and invariance properties. Under scaling of the independent variable, the seminorm of $\dot H^1$ is multiplied by $\tau^{n-2}$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space. In particular, in two dimensions the seminorm is scaling invariant, and even **conformally invariant**: $\|u\circ f\| = \|u\|$ for every conformal map $f$. In contrast, the full $H^1$ norm is not conformally invariant: the $\int u^2$ terms is not preserved by composition with $f$.

The seminorm is also what appears on the right side of Sobolev and Poincaré inequalities. For example: for every $u\in \dot H^1(M)$ we have 
$$\int_M |u-\bar u|^2\le C\int_M |\nabla u|^2$$
where $\bar u$ is the mean value of $u$ on $M$, i.e., $\int_M u$ divided by the volume of $M$.

Search for "homogeneous Sobolev space" to find more examples of where this concept shows up.

Comment: @Cortizol One source is the multi-volume *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators" by Hormander. Volume I introduces distributions, and Volume II concerns solving PDE in terms of them... But I recommend asking this as a question of its own (tagging as reference-request, pde, distribution-theory). You'll need to make it more concrete: partial or ordinary differential equations? What exactly "over distributions" means: do the equations involve distributions, or the solutions are thought as distributions? Etc.